# Please help make my infinite intersection proof more rigorous!

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I am working on problems from my textbook for self-study and would like to know how I can make my proof more rigorous - I am having trouble expressing what I am thinking mathematically. I want to show that the infinite intersection of open sets may not be open. To demonstrate this, I am using the sequence $A_n$ = $B_{1/n}((0,0))$, which is the ball with radius $\frac 1 n$ around the origin. Below is what I have:

Denote the infinite intersection of $A_n$ as $U$. We know that $(0,0) \in U$ and thus $(0,0) \in A_n$ for all $n$. Since for all $n$, $A_n$ is open, we also know that $B_{1/n}((0,0)) \subset U$. Let $r$ be the smallest radius of $A_n$ for all $n$. Then $B_r((0,0)) \subset B_{1/n}((0,0)) \subset U$. But since $\lim \frac 1 n \to 0$, $r=0$. Thus $B_r ((0,0)) = (0,0)$, which is closed as its complement is open.

Comment: Please study the edits I made to your post to improve your understanding of the correct use of MathJax on this site. Note on notation: when applying a function to a single point represented as an ordered pair, extra parentheses are generally *not* used. So that should be, for example, $A_n = B_{1/n}(0,0)$.

Comment: The statement "Since for all $n$, $A_n$ is open, we also know that $B_{1/n}(0,0)\subset U$ does not make any sense. It is not true, and does not have anything to do with the fact that $A_n$ is open for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your edits dfeuer, I tried looking up how to write the notation on the math.stackexchange Mathjax page, but did not know how to do some parts. As for the proof...I was trying to adapt the proof that finite intersections of open sets are open. It seems this is not the correct route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve said a couple of things exactly backwards.

> We know that $\langle 0,0\rangle\in U$ and thus $\langle 0,0\rangle\in A_n$ for all $n$.

No, it’s the other way around: we know that $\langle 0,0\rangle\in U$ **because** we know that $\langle 0,0\rangle\in A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$

It’s also not true that $B_{1/n}(\langle 0,0\rangle)\subseteq U$: the inclusion goes the other way. $U=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n$, so $U\subseteq A_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, which of course means that $U\subseteq B_{1/n}(\langle 0,0\rangle)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, by the definition of the sets $A_n$.

There is no smallest radius of the sets $A_n$: no matter what $r>0$ you choose, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<r$, and the radius of $A_n$ is then less than $r$. In fact this is what you really want; you’re just not using it quite right. You want to use it to prove that $\langle 0,0\rangle$ is the only point of $U$, so suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$. Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$; then $r>0$, so there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<r$, and you can easily check that $\langle x,y\rangle\notin A_n$ and hence $\langle x,y\rangle\notin U$. This shows that $U=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$, which, as you say, is closed.

However, a set can be both closed and open; $\varnothing$ is such a set, for example. Thus, it’s not enough to say that $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is closed: you must actually show that it’s not open. This is easy: if it were open, it would contain $B_\epsilon(\langle 0,0\rangle)$ for some $\epsilon>0$, and it clearly does not, since it does not contain (for instance) $\left\langle\frac{\epsilon}2,0\right\rangle$.

Comment: I was really hoping you'd show up here. Glad you did.

Comment: May I suggest a more old-school-geometric approach, avoiding the square roots and such?

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer; it looks like I have a lot to edit! I'll read through this closely and try rewriting my proof. Thanks again for your (and dfeuer's) help!

Comment: @dfeuer: My first choice, actually, was polar coordinates, but then I decided to stick to the most familiar way of looking at it.

Comment: @user2853043: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I meant older-school. If $P \in \Bbb R^2 \setminus O$, draw the circle with center $O$ and radius $OP$ ....

Comment: @dfeuer: My experience is that U.S. undergraduates are in general actually more comfortable with Cartesian geometry (as on the whole am I).

Comment: On the whole, I am too--all those crazy theorems about chords of circles make my head spin--but in my own non-definitive opinion a more visual approach is more intuitive in this case.

Comment: @dfeuer, OP probably said "Brian Scott" 3 times in the mirror first.

Comment: @dfeuer: Ah, now I see what you were getting at. I didn’t realize it before, because the visual approach is exactly what I had in mind when I wrote what I did!